# opening variable file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a program that involves the user opening a file in python. Here is the relevant code:

```
def fileopen():
    source = input("Enter the name of the source file (w/ extension): ")
    f = open("%s" %source, "r") #open the file
    filelist = f.read()
    f.close()
    print(filelist)
    encrypt(filelist)
```

this is resulting in the following error:

```
Enter the name of the source file (w/ extension): source

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Encrypt\Encrypt.py", line 27, in <module>
    fileopen()
  File "C:\Python27\Encrypt\Encrypt.py", line 2, in fileopen
    source = input("Enter the name of the source file (w/ extension): ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'source' is not defined
>>>
```

It was working when I was leaving it set as a static file (ex. source.txt) but I need to be able to select the file to use.

Comment: Is there a reason to prompt? Command line arguments are usually a simpler option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `input()`; use `raw_input()` here:

```
source = raw_input("Enter the name of the source file (w/ extension): ")
f = open(source, "r")
```

`input()` *evaluates* the input as a Python expression. If you typed `source` at the prompt, Python tries to look that up as a variable name.

```
>>> input('Gimme: ')
Gimme: source
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'source' is not defined
>>> input('Gimme: ')
Gimme: Hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Hello' is not defined
```

`raw_input()` gives you just a string, nothing else.